# Get "Content-Type" header of request in PHP

Tags: php, http, rest, http-headers

I'm implementing a REST service in PHP. This service should be able to support multiple input and output formats (JSON, XML). For that reason I want to check the request headers *"Accept"* and *"Content-Type"* for the type of content sent and requested by the client.

Accessing the *"Accept"* header is a simple as using `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']`. But accessing the *"Content-Type"* header seems to be a difficult task. I searched the PHP documentation and the web, but the only solution offered was the use of the PHP function `apache_request_headers()` which is only supported when PHP is installed as an Apache module, which is not true in my case.

So my question now: How can I access the header "Content-Type" of a request?

Comment: Remember that `$_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]` is not always available.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Normal (GET) requests do not have a `Content-Type` header. For POST requests it would appear as **`$_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]`**, with a value like multipart/form-data or application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

This is mandated by the CGI/1.1 specification: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3875.

Comment: There is a documented bug report for the built in PHP server. It should return `CONTENT_TYPE` but instead returns `HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE`. Hopefully its fixed in the near future. https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=66606&thanks=6

Comment: Although unusual, a GET request can have a Content-Type header and can include a request body.

Answer (score 25):

You'll need to manually instruct Apache to supply the `Content-Type` header (plus any other headers you want).

Pop something like this in your `.htaccess` file or virtual host:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE:%{HTTP:Content-Type},L]
```

And voila, you just synthesised your very own `$_SERVER['HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE']`!

**Edit:**

I assume you're running PHP as CGI with Apache so you can use verbs other than GET and POST, as most rest services do. If you're using another web server or largely unheard-of PHP SAPI, you'll need to use a similar trick; PHP as CGI simply doesn't have access to request headers outside the contents of `$_SERVER`, no matter what other mechanisms you use - `$_ENV`, `apache_request_headers()`, even the classes in the `php_http` extension will all be empty.

Comment: Thanks, that did it! I'm impressed :-)

Comment: Age-old problem with REST services on PHP/Apache rigs. I make a point of distributing the vhost with the application because they usually get pretty hefty. Glad it worked :)

Comment: @NeilE.Pearson Is there a way to allow `charset` in the header? I'm [having problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21720797/oauth-server-and-content-type-header) with it accepting it.

Comment: @BenSinclair as your question has been removed I'll assume an answer is no longer required ;)

Comment: This does not require **mod_rewrite** `SetEnvIfNoCase ^Content-Type "(.+)" CONTENT_TYPE=$1`

Comment: @BenSinclair That makes sense. I believe the media type in the response Content-Type: has the ;charset=UTF-8 appended but the form media type in the request does not. This is consistent with RFC6749 and the sad lack of UTF-8 specification for "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" is discussed in [http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#appendix-B](Appendix B)

Comment: This should be the selected answer!

Answer (score 6):

You can also get the content type (like "text/html") with this :

```
echo split(',', getallheaders()['Accept'])[0];
```

or

```
echo get_headers('http://127.0.0.1', 1)["Content-Type"]
```

---

*Update*

Like Benjamin said, `apache_request_headers` is available with FastCGI from 5.4.0 and from internal PHP server since 5.5.7.

Comment: Thanks for the info. From the documentation: "These functions are only available when running PHP as an Apache module.". As far as I know PHP is often run using FastCGI. This is exactly the case in my scenario. I personally prefer `$_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]`, it looks much cleaner.

Comment: Note that `apache_request_headers()` is available under FastCGI from PHP 5.4.0