# error handling and content-type in file_get_contents with get request

Tags: php

I have a PHP function here:

```
function TryGetJSON($URL) { //Attempts to retrieve the JSON at a URL, script terminates if failure
    function LogAndDie($msg) { error_log($msg); die(); }
    for($attempt = 0; $attempt < 3; $attempt++) { //Try 3 times to fetch URL
        $JSON = file_get_contents($URL); //Attempt to fetch, then check Response Header
        if( !$JSON && isset($http_response_header) && strstr($http_response_header[0], '503'))
            continue; //503 response: server was busy, so try again
        else
            break; //$JSON is populated, must be a 200 response
    }//$JSON is always false on 404, file_get_contents always returns false on read failure
    
    if(isset($http_response_header)) {
        if(strstr($http_response_header[0], '503')) //If still 503, then all our attempts failed
            LogAndDie('Could not get JSON file (' . $URL . '): ' . $http_response_header[0] . ' after 3 attempts.');
        if(!strstr($http_response_header[0], '200')) //If not a 200
            LogAndDie('Could not get JSON file (' . $URL . '): ' . $http_response_header[0]);
        if(!strstr($http_response_header[7], 'application/json') ) //Check Correct Content-Type
            LogAndDie('Wrong Content Type for (' . $URL . '). Received: ' . $http_response_header[7]);
        return $JSON;
    }
    if(!$JSON) LogAndDie('Could not get JSON file (' . $URL . ').'); //Catch all
}
```

The gist of the function is that it `die()`s and writes to the `error_log` if it fails to retrieve a JSON from a specified URL.  It reattempts 3 times in the event of `503`'s.

I have a couple main questions regarding it:

1. The `Content-Type` check isn't always right, because the index isn't always 7 on a GET request.  Am I suppose to loop over the entire `$http_response_header` with `strstr` for `Content-Type` and then check it?  Seems clumsy to me.  The [manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php) had pretty much nothing on this.  There has to be an easier way to handle that?
2. My `error_log` has lines like this on a `404`:

---

```
[25-Oct-2012 09:02:23] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(...) [<a href='function.file-get-contents'>function.file-get-contents</a>]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in ... on line 8
[25-Oct-2012 09:02:23] Could not get JSON file (...): HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

---

I'm only interested in keeping mine (the second line) and not filling my `error_log` with both.  I found `@` could be used to suppress this on `file_get_contents`, but that might suppress other warnings I might need to know about that I cannot predict.  Is there a way to just suppress that specific warning in this function?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519802/get-content-type-header-of-request-in-php) question, you can get the `content-type` header from the `$_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]` superglobal (I haven't checked, so I can't be sure). EDIT: Have now checked and it appears to be available only for POST requests.

for the `file_get_contents` question, you may as well suppress the warning if you don't want it, and you can explicitly test if it's returning false.

Just a note; Defining a function within a function is not a good idea - you'll get an error if you call the `TryGetJSON` function twice within the same script, as you can't define a function with the same name as one already defined.