# Detect content type in a request made with cURL

Tags: php, http, curl, httprequest, content-type

I am trying to send cURL request to a remote API server with this code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$options = array(CURLOPT_URL => 'http://minecms.info/update/index.php',
                   CURLOPT_POST => true,
                   CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
                   CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data,
                   CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-type: application/json'),
                   CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false
                  );
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

But I don't want users accessing the updates page on their browsers so I set a content type header on the request. The problem is that I don't know how to detect this content type on the remote server. Basically what I want is to check whether the client request has a `content type: application/json` set if yes it executes the rest of the code if not it just does `exit;`.

Thank you to anyone who would help in advance.

Comment: This could help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519802/get-content-type-header-of-request-in-php

Comment: @ilpaijin No i already read that question before, didn't really help, i did a google search for like 3 hours...

Comment: There is no reliable cross-environment way to check headers received in php. If it's apache, try `apache_request_headers();`

Comment: @Anthony I am trying to make this an open source CMS so everyone runs it on different server and i would want it to be competible with all servers

Comment: You want the cms platform to be open-source or just have the cms server you are running be an open cms? If you want to write a new cms, then setting the content-type header is a really weak approach that anyone could bypass.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `getallheaders()` and check whether the `Content-Type` is in place.

Give a look at the man http://www.php.net/manual/it/function.getallheaders.php for insights

---- EDIT INSIGHTS ----

And what about this one? (Which I'm currently using)

```
public function getAllHeaders()
{
    if(function_exists('getallheaders'))
    {
        return getallheaders();
    }

    $headers = array();

    foreach ($this->parameters as $key => $value)
    {
        if (substr($key, 0, 5) == 'HTTP_')
        {
            $headers[str_replace(" ", "-", ucwords(strtolower(str_replace("_", " ", substr($key, 5)))))] = $value;
        }

        if ($key == "CONTENT_TYPE")
        { 
            $headers["Content-Type"] = $value; 
        }   
    }

    return $headers;
}
```