# Response::view triggers download in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, response, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I am trying to display an HTTP Live Streaming playlist (m3u8 file) which is being generated by Laravel. In order to do this, I have a view (playlist.blade.php):

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:5
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
@foreach($videos as $video)
#EXTINF:4,
/videos/watch/{{ $video->file }}.ts
@endforeach
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

In my controller, I'm using the following code:

```
return Response::view('compilations.playlist', compact('videos'))->header('Content-Type', 'application/x-mpegurl');
```

To make up the view with the right headers.

When I throw up the file onto a static server like nginx, with the correct mime-type, the file displays in the browser, and works with Apple's `mediastreamvalidator`. When I try to access the file through the Laravel server, the browser downloads the file automatically (instead of displaying it) and it does not work with the `mediastreamvalidator`.

How can I make up the view, with the correct headers, and have it behave as the nginx server does (display in the browser, load properly in the verification tool / video players)?

Comment: If I understand well it works on nging but not on the default php server? Maybe it's related to this bug on the default php server? (See comment on the accepted request of this question) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519802/get-content-type-header-of-request-in-php

Comment: Yes, it works on nginx, but not when I use `php artisan serve` (or when using nginx + php-fpm). The thing is, when I use Postman or cURL to access the file, I get the right `Content-Type` header in the response, so I don't think that it is related to that bug.

Comment: That's weird. Well, as al alternative you can always use vagrant + laravel homestead and serve your local development environment through nginx (the default in homestead). Anyway I'd love to see an answer that makes this clear.

Comment: On my production server it's working via nginx as well but the response is being generated by Laravel, so nginx isn't involved. I just want to use `Response::view` and have it work properly without telling the browser to download the file.