# x-www-form-urlencoded or json HTTP POST

Tags: php, json, web-services, content-type

I'm making a webservice in which user must be able to post to the server with either Content-type json or x-www-form-urlencoded.

I'm trying to do this with a switch like this

```
$content_type = $_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"];
switch($content_type){
  case "application/json":
    //something must happen
    break;
  case "application/x-www-form-urlencoded":
    //something else must happen
    break;
```

But this isn't working. Can someone please tell me how to do this?

Comment: $_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]; Where do you have this from ? I never saw CONTENT_TYPE as a server variable. Did you check it with phpinfo() ?

Comment: I found it as an answer to another question on this site. I'll check it with phpinfo()

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get "Content-Type" header of request in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519802/get-content-type-header-of-request-in-php)

Comment: You're right, $_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]; won't work. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: @LorenzMeyer That is the question where I found $_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]

Comment: But that question also tells that is does not always work and what you can try.

Comment: Trying that now. I'm sorry, totally missed that. Thanks for your help