# Check user request my site is using URL visit or script src | link href request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Now i'm making my own kind of thing just work like [Rawgit](https://rawgit.com/),just in case Rawgit is down

And here is my PHP code

```
<?php
$urlquery = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$fullurl = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$code = file_get_contents($urlquery);

echo $code;

 ?>
```

This code is work find of some kind of script src | style link request

But when i try some like this

```
<?php
$urlquery = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$fullurl = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$code = file_get_contents($urlquery);


echo '<code style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">'.$code.'</code>'

 ?>
```

It look good from URL request but not work from script src | styel link request any more

And i'm thinking is that a way to check the user is using URL or some request look like this

```
<?php
$urlquery = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$fullurl = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$code = file_get_contents($urlquery);

echo $code;

if ( user is form URL visiting my site ) {
  echo '<code style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">'.$code.'</code>'
}else {
  //User is scripting
  echo $code
}

 ?>
```

Comment: I'm not PHP guy but i think it could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519802/get-content-type-header-of-request-in-php

Comment: Cross check : `echo $fullurl;`; may be it is creating wrong url.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) to check request is from Script SRC or Not

if direct or not src Header will look like :

```
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36     (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.24 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
DNT: 1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: __utma=111872281.760768228.1462861525.1462861525.1462882676.2; __utmz=111872281.1462861525.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)
```

if from src will look like :

```
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36     (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.24 Safari/537.36
Accept: */*
DNT: 1
Referer: http://localhost/b/jwplayer/test.txt.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: __utma=111872281.760768228.1462861525.1462861525.1462882676.2; __utmz=111872281.1462861525.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)
```

that is tested on firefox and chrome.

the diferent is from header **Accept:**

direct will "**`Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8`**"

from src will "**`*/*`**"

from css href "**`text/css,*/*;q=0.1`**"

so you can use script :

```
<?php
$acceptheader=explode(',',$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']);
if(in_array("text/html", $acceptheader)){
    echo '<pre class="prettyprint">var variable="i am direct & not from SRC";</pre>';
}else{
    echo 'var variable="i am from SRC";';
}
```

Dont forget add **header('Content-type: mime');** on Chrome CSS href is will not work with out set header "**text/css**".