# file_get_contents('php://input') returns empty when sending thru url parameter

Tags: php

I know this question has been already asked in the forum for several times but neither any of the answer worked for me. I still get empty string every time I try to send a data via a URL parameter.

This is the PHP code

```
            <?php   
                    if (!file_get_contents("data:,ok")) {
                              die("Houston, we have a stream wrapper problem.");
                         }
                    print "CONTENT_TYPE: " . $_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'] . "<BR />";
                    $data = file_get_contents('php://input');
                    print "DATA: <pre>";
                    var_dump($data);
                    $tempArray = json_decode(file_get_contents('generated.json'), true);
                    array_push($tempArray, $data);
                    $jsonData = json_encode($tempArray);
                    file_put_contents('generated.json', $jsonData);
                    print "</pre>"; 
            ?>
            <form method="post">
                <input type="text" name="name" value="ok" />
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/> 
            </form>
```

Example of passing a variable using url parameter

```
http://localhost/tests/testtest.php?name=what
```

Output:

```
            Notice: Undefined index: CONTENT_TYPE in C:\Apache24\htdocs\tests\testtest.php on line 5
            CONTENT_TYPE:
            DATA:
```

I have already set `allow_url_fopen = On`, set the `post_max_size = 8M` and still no hope. However when I try to send a data by click the submit button it send a raw data to the php (`string(21) "name=ok&submit=submit"`).

Anyone care to help? Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5519834/1005215

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is described in [php://input](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php)

> **php://input**
>
> php://input is a read-only stream that allows you to read raw data from the request body. In the case of POST requests, it is preferable to use php://input instead of $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA as it does not depend on special php.ini directives.

The important part is "`POST` reqest".

This means, when you say `http://www.example.com/tests/testtest.php?name=what`, you send a `GET` request and not a `POST` request. Therefore, there is no request body, and you cannot read anything through `php://input`.

---

To read form input passed as URL parameters, you may use the global [`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) variable.

When you use a POST request, you usually use the global [`$_POST`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) array, instead of reading the request body manually through `php://input`.

You may also consider [`$_REQUEST`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php), if you don't care if it is a POST or GET request. Although, be aware of [What's wrong with using $_REQUEST[]?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2142497/1741542)

Comment: Do you have any other method I can use to make it possible to send a data thru url parameter?

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`?

```
<?php

// Basic way, but has the risk of E_NOTICE when it is undefined.
var_dump($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);

// Safe way
var_dump((string)filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'QUERY_STRING'));
```